# How to pass additional compiler/linker options in msbuild command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

So the thing is I am trying to do something that requires adding additional compiler and linker options while building a project. I do not want that option to be added to the default compile options so that it is not messed up for others. In visual studio I can add additional options to the compiler and linker by editing the properties of the project. It will be good to have a one-time switch between adding or not adding these additional options. Say in command line using `msbuild /compilerOption /linkerOption` to add these addiontal options. Or having a configure file that can be loaded by `msbuild` command. Is there a good way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how, but you could look towards [MSBuild parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx), [schema elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx) and [compiler options](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Setting-Compiler-Options-in-MSBuild-projects)

Comment: Visual Studio provides a [CL environment variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kezkeayy(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify compiler and linker options.  You should be able to use it to augment your MSBuild call.